# Determine the class which called call_user_func_array

Tags: php

Is it possible to find out the name of the class that called `call_user_func_array` method? Here's an example:

```
// ClassA
public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
{
    return call_user_func_array([ClassB::some_method(static::$some_arg), $method], $args);
}

// ClassB
public static function some_method($some_arg) {
    // how do I find out that some_method was called by ClassA?
}
```

The goal is for `some_method` to know that it was called by `ClassA`. Also note that `ClassB::some_method(static::$some_arg)` calls the method statically, and then `$method` in `call_user_func_array` is chained with it.

On a side note, I tried to substitute `call_user_func_array` with `return DB::some_method(static::$some_arg)->$method(extract($args));`, but it didn't work as expected. Any reasons why?

## Edit

I have a slight complication to the initial question. Imagine now that there is a class `ClassA_Child`:

```
class ClassA_Child extends ClassA {}
```

`ClassA_Child` can now call `ClassB`'s method -- `some_method`. The call would be

```
ClassA_Child::some_method;
```

This is valid because `ClassA_Child` is a subclass of `ClassA`. However, if I do the following:

```
// ClassB
public static function some_method($some_arg) {
    $bt = debug_backtrace();
    $caller_class = (isset($bt[1]['class']) ? $bt[1]['class'] : null);
    echo $caller_class; // ClassA, and NOT ClassA_Child!
}
```

Note that the backtrace indicates that `some_method` was called by the base class `ClassA`, not `ClassA_Child`. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I saw your Edit, as I mentioned did you simply try to replace $bt[1] with $bt[2]? By going on level up the stack you can see if the static invocation happened on ClassA or ClassA_Child

Comment: I think some_method should receive a set of parameters that will allow it to return a correct and consistent result.  What if you need to call the function from several places in the same class and need slightly different results. Also this type of coding is difficult to document and maintain as the project and team grows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some intro is due for this answer. First it would be nice to discuss (those kind of programmers social evenining in front of a beer) **why** you would ever want to have such a complicated indirect referentials, I worked with fairly complicated ORMs and they didn't require so many levels of indirection and abstraction.

Another important note is that someone will probably comment with some very philosophic argument that you should **not** adopt the `debug_backtrace()` solution for this and that reason. It is bad practice indeed, but guess what, I'm also using it. Just be warned, it is very fragile coding with a lot of situations ready to backstab.

Here is the relevant code:

```
class A {
  static $some_arg = "ciao";

  public static function __callStatic($method, $args) {
    return call_user_func_array(array(B::some_method(static::$some_arg), $method), $args);
  }
}

class B {
  public static function some_method($some_arg) {
    print "B::some_method (" . $some_arg . ")\n";

    // obtain the caller class
    $bt = debug_backtrace();
    $caller_class = (isset($bt[1]['class']) ? $bt[1]['class'] : null);
    print ".. i was called by " . $caller_class . "\n";

    return "C";
  }
}

class C {
  public static function other_method($arg1, $arg2) {
    print "C::other_method called\n";
  }
}

A::other_method(10, 20);
```

Output:

```
B::some_method (ciao)
.. i was called by A
C::other_method called
```

**UPDATE #2**

If the `__callStatic()` is invoked on a sub-class of `ClassA` instead of directly in `ClassA` (like `ClassA_Child::doSomething()`), you can replace the following line of code to obtain this information. Note that this change (going up the call stack one extra level) would **fail** if you script invoked `__callStatic()` itself directly (which should never happen, anyway).

```
$caller_class = (isset($bt[2]['class']) ? $bt[2]['class'] : null);
```

**UPDATE**

I had to edit my answer for the "side note" part of the question. I was wrong because I thought that some_method() would return a static class name (a string basically), while it actually returns an instance.

Well, in this case you can absolutely ditch the call_user_func_array() if you want, but it would be my preferred solution to use that one. The only mistake you are doing is the extract($args) part, that function does **not** do what you think, it actually does something completely different, check the man page.

What you need here is the spread operator, as in this example:

```
class B {
  static function factory() {
    print "called B::factory()\n";
    return new C();
  }
}

class C {
  function m($a, $b) {
    print "called c::m() a=$a b=$b\n";
  }
}

$func_name = "m";
$func_args = array(10, 20);
B::factory()->$func_name(...$func_args);
```

Output:

```
called B::factory()
called c::m() a=10 b=20
```

Comment: I appreciate your thorough answer! Is there a safer alternative to `debug_backtrace`? As for the side note, `some_method` in `ClassB` returns an object of `ClassB`, and then $method, which is invoked in `call_user_func_array` is chained on that object.

Comment: No, i don't think there are other ways. As I mentioned I also use the same technique even though it's not really great practice. Of course other than passing `__CLASS__` as argument to the called function itself..

Comment: Thank you. My problem now is that a child class of `ClassA` (e.g. `ClassAChild`) actually calls `some_method` in `ClassB`, and not `ClassA` itself. I get `ClassA` in debug_backtrace. Is it possible to get `ClassAChild`?

Comment: I didn't get your last comment, can you show some working conceptual code similar to mine? Something I can execute. It might be sufficient to tune the $bt[1] part, if you use $bt[2] you go up twice in the stack call. Try to var_dump(debug_backtrace()) in the relevant code, you might see what i mean.

Comment: Can you please take a look at my edit? I tried to explain my current problem in more detail